# How to remove the leading indentation of member classes/functions/variables in C++ code?

Tags: c++, parsing, clang-format

I want to remove the leading indentation of member classes/functions/variables in C++ code. For example, I want to convert

```cpp
class Type {
    int var;
public:
    void f1();
    class Inner {
        // ...
    };
    double f2(int i)
    {
        // ....
    } 
}
```

to

```cpp
class Type {
int var;
public:
void f1();
class Inner {
    // ...
};
double f2(int i)
{
    // ....
} 
}
```

Note that only the leading indentation in class declaration is removed.

I checked options of `clang-format` but failed to find one. How to achieve this?

By the way, the motivation of this question is to comment out function bodies with zero coverage. I prepared a simple script that treats a curly brace beginning a line as one brace wrapping a function body. Then if all lines in the body have zero coverage, they are commented out as a whole. The style used permits such parsing rule and the script works well for this special use case. The only exception is the case of inline functions defined in class.

Comment: Why would you want to do this horrible thing?

Comment: To me this seems to make the code totally ugly and very hard to read. Perhaps it would be more productive to ask how to improve the script?

Comment: Why not write function body in cpp files, so function braces have no indentation.

Comment: Your motivation made even less sense. The only way you can correctly parse a function body is to, well, parse it. Not go through weird formatting voodoo and hope the stars align.

Comment: @n.m. Because I need to improve code coverage of an old code base. Much of it was not used at present, so commenting them out temporarily is a good choice.

Comment: You're probably unlikely to get an answer, because the people who could try to answer it will immediately think of all the C++ code where this idea just won't work. Consider for instance class templates (how do you even define coverage there?), nested classes, namespaces, lambda's, function try-catch blocks, defaulted functions, ....

Comment: @MSalters Thx, the code I am dealing with does not have that complexity. The coverage report is generated by `gcov` and 'lcov` and class/function templates seem to have non-zero coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the following in the clang-format file,

`IndentWidth: '0'`

That said, I dont think you need to do this, just comment out the unused code.

Comment: This disable indentation globally, I only need to disable the first level in-class indentation